# What is Ruby's equivalent to pythons xrange?

Tags: python, ruby, lazy-evaluation, xrange

Apparently `xrange` in python is faster than `range`. because `xrange` creates a sequence of objects lazily. However `range` creates objects in memory.

What I'd like to know is what is Ruby's equivalent of pythons xrange?

Comment: I don't know Ruby, but I googled "lazy range in ruby" and the results seem to be pretty helpful.

Comment: I've searched this myself, but I can't use it like in python. For exmaple in python:
`for i in xrange(m):
    matrix.append(map(int, raw_input().split()))`

@timgeb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby ranges are already lazy, like Python 3 `range`. Just use a range:

```
1..10  # includes endpoint
1...10 # excludes endpoint
```

Idiomatic iteration in Ruby often doesn't involve ranges, though. For example, if you want to do a thing `n` times, like in your comment:

```
n.times { do_something }
```

Comment: Oh my, is that so?